# Perlin Noise Attempt

Tags: c, graphics, perlin-noise

I am trying my attempt at Perlin Noise (3-dimensional) as outlined in this document: http://lodev.org/cgtutor/randomnoise.html

However, this is what I'm getting. 
[image: perlin noise attempt]
It looks like the smoothing isn't working. You can see blocks the size of the 'size' parameter. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
%ffp

ctl(1):standard,"Size",range=(1,256), pos=(300,20), size=(120,*),val=64,track, action=preview

onFilterStart:
{
allocArray(9,64,64,64,4);   // Array for noise depth
  for(int z = 0; z < 64; z++)
  for(int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
  for(int x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
    fputArray(9,x,y,z,(float)(rand() % 32768) / 32768.0);
  }

return false;
}

forEveryTile:
{
double fractX,fractY,fractZ,xx,yy,zz;
int x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,col;
double value = 0.0, value2 = 0.0, size, isize=(float)ctl(1);
// int X=screen Width, int Y=screen Height

  for(int y = 0; y < Y; y++) {
  for(int x = 0; x < X; x++) {
  //for(int z = 0; z < 64; z++) {
  value2 = 0.0;
  size = isize;

  while (size >=1.0) {
  xx=(float)x/size;
  yy=(float)y/size;
  zz=(float)clock()/size;
  fractX = xx - (int)(xx);
  fractY = yy - (int)(yy);
  fractZ = zz - (int)(zz);
  x1 = ((int)(xx) + 64) % 64;
  y1 = ((int)(yy) + 64) % 64;
  z1 = ((int)(zz) + 64) % 64;
  x2 = (x1 + 64- 1) % 64;
  y2 = (y1 + 64- 1) % 64;
  z2 = (z1 + 64- 1) % 64;

  value=0.0;
  value += fractX     * fractY     * fractZ     * fgetArray(9,z1,y1,x1);
  value += fractX     * (1 - fractY) * fractZ     * fgetArray(9,z1,y2,x1);
  value += (1 - fractX) * fractY     * fractZ     * fgetArray(9,z1,y1,x2);
  value += (1 - fractX) * (1 - fractY) * fractZ     * fgetArray(9,z1,y2,x2);

  value += fractX     * fractY     * (1 - fractZ) * fgetArray(9,z2,y1,x1);
  value += fractX     * (1 - fractY) * (1 - fractZ) * fgetArray(9,z2,y2,x1);
  value += (1 - fractX) * fractY     * (1 - fractZ) * fgetArray(9,z2,y1,x2);
  value += (1 - fractX) * (1 - fractY) * (1 - fractZ) * fgetArray(9,z2,y2,x2);

  value2 += value*size;
  size /= 2.0;
  }

  col=(int)((float)(128.0 * value2 / isize));
  col=max(min(col,255),0);
  psetp(x,y,RGB(col,col,col));

//} //z
} //x
} //y

return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the motivation to use `clock()` as `z` coordinate? Obviously you want to create a cloud animation, but `clock` may yield different values of `z` for each run-through of the inner loop, which means you are doing the interpolation on different animation frames. If "for every tile" means "for each `z`", just enumerate the possible `z` values.

Comment: That's very true but even if I take z out of the equation entirely, I still get these blocky results. I was looping z through a loop as well to get a true 3 dimensional noise but for debugging, I took it out and made it into a 2 dimensional loop. So I don't think z is the cause of the problem.

Comment: So the result is blocky even for 2d noise?

Comment: Even if I assign z a static value like 64, the results are still blocky which leads me to believe it isn't an issue with the z loop. But I could be wrong. I can post an image if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is kind of hard to read as written.

For Perlin noise start out with a integer noise function, that behaves like a hash.

```
float noise(int x, int y, int z) { return hash(x+y*5+z*7); }
```

or

```
float noise(int x, int y, int z) { return array[x%w+y%h*w+z%d*w*h]; }
```

Those are just examples. The important part is that noise(x,y,z) = noise(x,y,z). The noise function has to return the same value for the same parameters every time.

There is a problem though: The noise function only takes integer parameters! But we would like to sample it at float values.

```
float noisesample (float x, float y, float z) { ... }
```

The easiest way to to that is using linear filtering. Any positive float value is between (int)pos and ((int)pos)+1. At sub-position pos-(int)pos. This gets us:

```
float Lerp(float a, float b, float f) { return a+(b-a)*f; }
```

Where f is the sub-position in the [0..1] range and a,b are the values to the left and right. If f is 0, Lerp returns a, if it is 1, it returns b. In between it does linear interpolation.

So use this for a simple 1D noisesample function:

```
float noisesample(float x) { return Lerp(noise((int)x), noise((int)x+1), fract(x) }
```

with

```
float fract(float x) { return x-(int)x; }
```

I am using (int)x liberally here, it is the same as floor(x) if x is positive.

To go from a single parameter noisesample to x,y is easy: Do the Lerp twice for x at y and y+1, and Lerp between those:

```
float noisesample(float x, float y) {
    float y0 = Lerp(noise((int)x,(int)y), noise((int)x+1,(int)y), fract(x) }
    float y1 = Lerp(noise((int)x,(int)y+1), noise((int)x+1,(int)y+1), fract(x) }
    return Lerp ( y0, y1, fract(y) );
}
```

First interpolate x, twice, then interpolate between the results in y. In total we sample noise() 4 times. I leave it as an exercise how to write noisesample ( float x, float y, float z). It will sample noise() eight times and call Lerp 7 times.

All that got us is that we can sample noise (somewhat smooth - there are smoother ways!) at float coordinates. And that is what we need to make perlin noise!

```
float perlin(float x, float y, float z, int oc=4) {
     // maybe: x = x*2^oc, y, z... 
    float r = 0;
    float s = 1;
    for ( int i=0; i<oc; i++ ) {
        r += noisesample(x,y,z) * s;
        s/=2.0f; // to taste
        x/=2.0f;
        y/=2.0f;
        z/=2.0f; 
    }
    return r; 
}
```

The key idea is to understand sampling. It's just a combination of sampling a simple integer noise function.